# How to use/decompress the file made by img2py

Tags: wxpython, pygame

I have used `img2py` to convert an image into a `.py` file. But how to use that converted file in pygame. Is there any specific code for it?

Comment: Why did you convert this image ? Why don't you use normal image - PNG, JPG ?

Comment: I have used pyinstaller to convert my python script into an executable file but whatever images I have used I need to add them into the dist folder.I want a way to hide them from the user.So I came across img2py but i'm unable to decompress that thing(py Embedded image) or whatever it is.It would be very kindful if you tell any other way of hiding those images or how to use that embedde code which img2py makes.

Comment: `img2py` is part of `wxPython` not `pygame` so search solution in `wxPython` docs.

Comment: If you have image in code so it is some kind of string -open that file in editor and see. Pygame can read image from string [pygame.image.fromstring()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring) but I don't know if it can be PNG converted to string.

Comment: You could create script in `PyGame` which loads image and convert it to own string (`pygame.image.tostring()`) and than you can use this string with `pygame.image.fromstring()`

Answer (score 2):

The `PyEmbeddedImage` class has a GetData method (or Data property) that can be used to fetch the raw data of the embedded image, in PNG format.